# Correlation by key on Java Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, mapreduce, statistics

I have a JavaPairRDD with ratings given by several users on some movies:

```
<< User1,User2 >
 < rate1,rate2 >>
```

(the movie Id has been dropped, but there are several records for each couple of users). 
I want to see if there is a correlation between two users. Is it possible to apply some sort of correlation by key?

***Thanks in advance.***